# A visually pleasing way of displaying the cluster assignment of a sample with respect to time

Tags: clustering

What are some of the more visually appealing ways to represent cluster assignments of a sample?

Usually the scatter plot works well but in this instace I am more insterested as to which cluster the sample is assigned to with respect to time.  The use case is anomoly detection in the samples pictured below the 2nd half of the sample is when the anomoly appears.

I am currently representing it via a bar chart. It is fine for me to judge the effectiveness of my code but doesnt look great.. The sample number or time is on the x-axis, and the cluster assignment is on the y-axis.

Any tips?

[image]